# Masonry Desandro grid height not fit the items after append item with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, masonry

This my first init code (Before append item with ajax):

```
 $('#edrea-ajax-wrapper').imagesLoaded( function() {
        $('#edrea-ajax-wrapper').masonry({
            itemSelector: '.edrea-card',
            transitionDuration: '1.4s',
            columnWidth: '.edrea-grid-sizer'
        });
    });
```

And this the code on my ajax:

```
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST", 
      url: ajax_url,
      dataType: 'html',
      data: {
         action:'edrea_load_more',
         count: total_posts
      },
      success: function( res ){

         if( res.length > 0 ) {
             var $content = $( res );
             $('#edrea-ajax-wrapper').imagesLoaded().done( function() {
                  $('#edrea-ajax-wrapper').append( $content ).masonry( 'appended', $content );
              });
             $('#edrea-ajax-wrapper').masonry('layout');
          } 
        },
   });
```

But, after I reload the page atleast once, the masonry work properly. This thing is only happens when I open the page on first time (Incognito mode or If after I clear the cache).

Thanks for the help!

I've been try use imagesLoaded plugin from Desandro itself, but still got this problem.

Comment: I figure it out, but not really what I want. The images/thumbnail should have same height and the grid height will fit the items properly.